# Array of entities / PHP / MongoDB / Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, symfony

Simple question :

I am using `mongoDB`, `Symfony 3.4`, and the `DoctrineMongoDBBundle`.
How can I create a value in an `mongoDB` entity that is an array of entities

For example : Have a conversation entity with a value message in it that is an array of entities message

Example in `json` :

```
{
    "id_of_the_conversation": 367,
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Hello i need help !",
            "send_by": 34,
            "received_by": 22
        }
        {
            "id": 2,
            "content": "Stack stack",
            "send_by": 22,
            "received_by": 34
        }
        {
            "id": 3,
            "content": "Maybe someone ?",
            "send_by": 34,
            "received_by": 22
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/bidirectional-references.html#self-referencing-many-to-many ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add comment on another post so I make my own post.

What @iiirxs said is right.

You hav to do the 2 Document Classes and Make annotation like you want.

If you want the `Messages` to have their own Collection, you annotate with `ReferenceMany`.
If you want the the `Messages` inside the COnversation Document, you make an `EmbedMany`

[Embed Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/embedded-mapping.html)

[References Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/reference-mapping.html#reference-mapping)

Then, you just have to `set` or `add` `Messages` in the Collection `messages` property of `Conversation` class.

When you save, all documents (Conversion AND Message of you Reference, only Conversation whit Message in it if you embed) will be saved.

From you original question, it seems you want to Embed.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should create two entities(in MongoDb these are called documents):

```
<?php

/** @Document */
class Message
{
    /** @Id(strategy="INCREMENT") */
    private $id;

    /** @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Conversation") */
    private $conversation;

    /** @Field(type="string") */
    private $content;

    /** @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User") */
    private $send_by;

    /** @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User") */
    private $received_by;
}

/** @Document */
class Conversation
{
    // ...

    /** @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Message") */
    private $messages;
}
```

You can read the full documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/bidirectional-references.html)

Comment: but when i will create a new message it will create a new document right ? and i like to have only one document for each conversation ... tell me if i am right but i think that if there are like 300 people messaging 300 * message = documents ... it will not have so mutch documents ?